# VBA: Quickest way to copy and paste rows of data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wondering if there is a quicker way to copy and paste data from one column of a worksheet to another column of a worksheet. This is a sample code of what I have and it runs slow as it has more than 10000 rows of data to copy for each column that I'm copying. The data that I'm copying from does not have a fixed range.

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
    ws.Cells(i, "AG") = bl.Cells(i, "F")
    ws.Cells(i, "AH") = bl.Cells(i, "G")
    ws.Cells(i, "AB") = bl.Cells(i, "N")
    ws.Cells(i, "AC") = bl.Cells(i, "R")
    ws.Cells(i, "BF") = bl.Cells(i, "S")
    ws.Cells(i, "AA") = bl.Cells(i, "U")
    ws.Cells(i, "BA") = bl.Cells(i, "X")
    ws.Cells(i, "BQ") = bl.Cells(i, "AA")
    ws.Cells(i, "B") = bl.Cells(i, "AB")
    ws.Cells(i, "A") = bl.Cells(i, "AD")
    ws.Cells(i, "BW") = bl.Cells(i, "AK")
    ws.Cells(i, "BH") = bl.Cells(i, "AL")
    ws.Cells(i, "BR") = bl.Cells(i, "AM")
    ws.Cells(i, "AL") = bl.Cells(i, "AP")
    ws.Cells(i, "AP") = bl.Cells(i, "BA")
    ws.Cells(i, "AQ") = bl.Cells(i, "BB")
    ws.Cells(i, "AU") = bl.Cells(i, "BC")
    ws.Cells(i, "AO") = bl.Cells(i, "BK")
    ws.Cells(i, "AT") = bl.Cells(i, "BO")
Next i
```

Comment: try to give feedback to answer to questions you posted on SO. You have not accepted anyh answer yet, this will affect you trying to get help in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy whole columns instead of cells !

```
ws.Range("AG2:AH" & lastrow) = bl.Range("F2:G" & lastrow) '2 cols at once here
ws.Range("AB2:AB" & lastrow) = bl.Range("N2:N" & lastrow) '.Value is implicit
```

(and so on..) should be 1000 times faster.

Exchange of data between VBA and Excel is very expensive for CPU. Transfering large blocks is therefore more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
ws.Range("AG2:AG" & lastrow).Value = bl.Range("F2:F" & lastrow).Value
ws.Range("AH2:AH" & lastrow).Value = bl.Range("G2:G" & lastrow).Value
ws.Range("AB2:AB" & lastrow).Value = bl.Range("N2:N" & lastrow).Value
```

and so on for the rest of the columns

Answer (score 0):

other than the answers provided above which worked for me, i posted another similar question which has another answer from a different user which i thought i should share here to benefit others looking around in SO.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41951959/7483682