# Excel VBA: Printing data from spreadsheet to text file takes too long

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code to copy and rearrange the required data columns from a master spreadsheet and save it as a text file.
What my code does is the following:
1) Ask the user to locate the master spreadsheet
2) Copy and rearrange the required data columns to the working spreadsheet containing the macro
3) Ask the user to type in the name of text file
4) Print the data from working spreadsheet to text file

```
Sub import()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim bl As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim dataArr As Variant
Dim fpath As String
Dim txtfile As String
Dim baseline As Workbook

'Opens file dialog to ask user to select baseline file
MsgBox ("Please select baseline file for output.")
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Select Baseline File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        fpath = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        MsgBox ("No file selected. Stopping macro")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

Set baseline = Workbooks.Open(fpath)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set bl = baseline.Sheets(1)

lastrow = bl.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear

'This block of code copies data columns from baseline file to working spreadsheet
ws.Range("AG2:AG" & lastrow) = bl.Range("F2:F" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AH2:AH" & lastrow) = bl.Range("G2:G" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AB2:AB" & lastrow) = bl.Range("N2:N" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AC2:AC" & lastrow) = bl.Range("R2:R" & lastrow)
ws.Range("BF2:BF" & lastrow) = bl.Range("S2:S" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AA2:AA" & lastrow) = bl.Range("U2:U" & lastrow)
ws.Range("BA2:BA" & lastrow) = bl.Range("X2:X" & lastrow)
ws.Range("BQ2:BQ" & lastrow) = bl.Range("AA2:AA" & lastrow)
ws.Range("B2:B" & lastrow) = bl.Range("AB2:AB" & lastrow)
ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow) = bl.Range("AD2:AD" & lastrow)
ws.Range("BW2:BW" & lastrow) = bl.Range("AK2:AK" & lastrow)
ws.Range("BH2:BH" & lastrow) = bl.Range("AL2:AL" & lastrow)
ws.Range("BR2:BR" & lastrow) = bl.Range("AM2:AM" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AL2:AL" & lastrow) = bl.Range("AP2:AP" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AP2:AP" & lastrow) = bl.Range("BA2:BA" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AQ2:AQ" & lastrow) = bl.Range("BB2:BB" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AU2:AU" & lastrow) = bl.Range("BC2:BC" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AO2:AO" & lastrow) = bl.Range("BK2:BK" & lastrow)
ws.Range("AT2:AT" & lastrow) = bl.Range("BO2:BO" & lastrow)

txtfile = InputBox("Type in name of audience file for output")
Do While txtfile = vbNullString
    MsgBox ("Name of output audience file is not entered. Please try again.")
    txtfile = InputBox("Type in name of audience file for output")
Loop

'Write values from copied spreadsheet to text file
dataArr = ws.UsedRange.Value
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & txtfile & ".txt")
    For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
        .writeline Join(Application.Index(dataArr, i, 0), vbTab)
    Next i
    .Close
End With

MsgBox ("Macro completed execution. File saved as " & txtfile & ".txt")

End Sub
```

2) executed without problems when I first coded it. When I run it again today, 2) does not get executed, and the text file output is blank. The master spreadsheet contains >30000 rows of data.

Also, is it possible to copy and rearrange the master spreadsheet and print it directly to the text file?

---

**EDIT**
Ok so i changed the copy and pasting and it works. The next problem I have now is printing the data to text file. It takes very long to print the data from spreadsheet to text file with the current code that I have. Is there an efficient way of printing it?

Comment: please take your time to give feedback to your previous questions. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`ws.Range("AG2:AG" & lastrow) = bl.Range("F2:F" & lastrow)` try

`bl.Range("F2:F" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("AG2:AG" & lastrow)`

it should work